# Replace field value with sequence number

Tags: shell, unix

I have scenario like this

file1 has

```
cat file1
aa~bb~1~dd
xx~yy~2~kk
cc~ff~3~pp
.......
```

I want to update the file like this

```
cat file2
aa~bb~20~dd
xx~yy~21~kk
cc~ff~22~pp
.......
```

tried with the below code but not working

```
seq_nr=20
i=1
while [i -le 10 ]
do
seq_nr=`expr 20 + 1`
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="~"} NR==i {$3=$seq_nr} {print} file1 > file2
i= `expr i +1`
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one-liner:

```
awk -F~ -v OFS='~' '$3=19+NR' file
```

with your example:

```
kent$  echo "aa~bb~1~dd
xx~yy~2~kk
cc~ff~3~pp"| awk -F~ -v OFS='~' '$3=19+NR'
aa~bb~20~dd
xx~yy~21~kk
cc~ff~22~pp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awk one-liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="~"} {$3+=19}1' file1 > file2

cat file2
aa:bb:20:dd
xx:yy:21:kk
cc:ff:22:pp
```

OR pure BASH code:

```
IFS='~' && while read v1 v2 v3 v4; do
   echo "$v1:$v2:$((v3+19)):$v4"
done < file
```

Comment: seq_nr is not constant and the file has about 31 fields

Comment: Input file can have any # of file with awk command I suggested.

Comment: if suppose I am having 3 records it is coming as 
aa~bb~21~dd
xx~yy~2~kk
cc~ff~3~pp
aa~bb~1~dd
xx~yy~22~kk
cc~ff~3~pp